# Laravel4/PHP: extending a class within different namespaced levels

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, extend

When I extend a class that lives in the same directory level it works fine, but when the extending class lives a lateral-sub directory level, it does not.  Everything is namespaced.  Below is my dir struct and the relevant code.

Dir Struct:

```
myproj\app\lib\Myproj\
                  |- ...
                  |- Abc\
                      |-  Sublvl1\
                              |- Sublvl1Controller.php
                      |- AbcBaseController.php
                      |- XyzController.php
```

composer.json:

```
"psr-0": {
    MyProj\\": "app/lib"
}
```

The Base Class that I want to extend in various places:
\app\lib\MyProj\Abc\AbcBaseController.php:

```
<?php namespace MyProj\Abc;

class AbcBaseController extends \BaseController 
{
    public function __construct()
    {   dd('inside AbcBaseController');  // testing that the class is being applied when extended...
```

app\lib\MyProj\Abc\XyzController.php:

```
<?php namespace MyProj\Abc;
class XyzController extends AbcBaseController // works fine
{
```

app\lib\MyProj\Abc\Sublvl1\Sublvl1Controller.php:

```
<?php namespace MyProj\Abc\Sublvl1;

use MyProj\Abc\AbcBaseController;

class Sublvl1Controller extends AbcBaseController   // does not work
{
    ...
```

The AbcBaseController is not applied when inside the MyProj\Abc\Sublvl1 namespace, even though I import it with the "use" statement.  However, the AbcBaseController *is* applied when inside the MyProj\Abc namespace.

Any insight greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a constructor on Sublvl1Controller? If so, are you calling `parent::__construct()` ?

Comment: That did the trick, thank you.  Yes a constructor was there but it did not call parent::__construct.  Why is it not necessary for the Xyz class in the same directory?

Comment: It would be necessary if it had a constructor, my guess is that it did not.  Its a quirk of PHP that child class constructors do not automatically call the parent constructor.  If a child class has no constructor, then creating a new object would implicitly call the parent::__construct

Comment: correct again, the Xyz class does not have a constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your child class is not calling the parent's constructor:

```
class Sublvl1Controller extends AbcBaseController   
{

    public function __construct( ) 
    {
        parent::__construct();  // You need this

    //...
```